# How to completely remove pure-ftpd-mysql from Ubuntu Server 12.04.2?

Tags: 12.04, pure-ftpd

I have tried removing `pure-ftpd-mysql` with the following commands without success:

```
apt-get remove --purge
apt-get autoremove --purge
apt-get purge 
apt-get clean
deborphan --guess-dev | xargs apt-get -y remove --purge
```

Everytime I run these I get the following and the system hangs:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED
  pure-ftpd-mysql*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 699 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 89500 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing pure-ftpd-mysql ...
```

I then have to tell the system to reboot and then run:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Has anyone got any ideas how I can completely remove this package so I can re-install it. 
Even if I try an `install -f` it gives the same results.

Comment: Forgot to add this is the exact result it comes back with note the bottom line with the hash # Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 89567 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing pure-ftpd-mysql ...
#Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 89567 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing pure-ftpd-mysql ...
#'

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my own issue. Though i would not recommend this, After all the un-install processes failed, i eventually gave in and manually located all the remaning files that had anything to do with pure-ftpd and removed them all manually, this then allowed the removal to complete.

Using Webmin file manager I did a search for everything that matched pure-ftpd, pure-ftpd-mysql and pure- and deleted them all. There were about 66 files still remaining.

I have since managed to successfully re install pure-ftpd